# zGuide for zeroMQ fails compilation

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to build the zguide c++ examples, but the compilation fails. Here is the error ouput:

```
asyncsrv.cpp: In member function ‘void client_task::start()’:
asyncsrv.cpp:37:70: error: cannot convert ‘zmq::socket_t’ to ‘void*’ in initialization zmq::pollitem_t items[] = {{client_socket_, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0}};

asyncsrv.cpp: In member function ‘void server_task::run()’: asyncsrv.cpp:140:52: error: cannot convert ‘zmq::socket_t’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void zmq::proxy(void*, void*, void*)’ zmq::proxy(frontend_, backend_, nullptr);
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe a version incompatibility between your installed ZMQ and the example code you're trying to run... you mind giving both your ZMQ version and the link to the example code?

Comment: zmqversion is 4.1.3 and the zGuide has the latest tag v2.2-1024-g40230a3 and commit sha1 40230a37eb45d8564733bedc08c333190387df3d. The C samples are build fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a C++11 compiler , see that your zmq.hpp is latest and replace the line

```
zmq::pollitem_t items[] = {{client_socket_, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0}};
```

by

```
std::vector<zmq::pollitem_t> items = {{static_cast<void *>(client_socket_), 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0}};
```

and the line

```
zmq::proxy(frontend_, backend_, nullptr);
```

by

```
zmq::proxy(static_cast<void *>(frontend_), static_cast<void *>(backend_), nullptr);
```

Comment: I hit this issue on gcc 5, while it compiled fine on clang